# Change in the number of positive zeros of a continuous function.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, exponential-function, rolles-theorem

Let $f(x)$ be any continuous function, then is it true that  $$Z^{+}\left(\alpha f(x)+(x+\beta)f'(x)\right)\leq Z^{+}\left(f'(x)\right)+1$$

where $\alpha>1$ is a real number and $\beta$ is any positive integer. $Z^+$ denotes the number of positive zeros.

Note: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial then it's easy to see that the above inequality holds.

Any help or small hint will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not easy to see even for a polynomial.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put $1$ in the inequality. what about this now? Any help, please.

Comment: Now it might be true for a polynomial, but not for any function in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This problem was an approach to solve this original problem. Can you please take a look at this once, and give me any hint or suggestion. I just want to make sure that it is correct. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155919/does-this-function-have-at-most-3-positive-zeros

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a function with a graph like this:
[image: graph]

It is surely smooth, and the flat parts are not quite horizontal, so $f'(x)>0$, and $f(x)<0$, and the steep parts can be made arbitrarily steep. So there are as many roots as we want in the LHS expression, but none in the RHS.

So no, the inequality does not hold.